# How to force child components to rerender?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, reactjs

I'm currently initializing child components in the parent and putting them into an array. I'm passing a function into the children's props that just gets state.

```
 <QuestionContainer
    error={ () => this.state.currentError }
 />
```

The problem is that when I do `this.setState({ currentError: x })` in the parent the child won't rerender because the error prop hasn't actually changed. I've tried `this.forceUpdate` to no avail.

I know I could design it in a way where I don't need to initialize the child components into an array, but I'm wondering how I would force a rerender in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

```
<QuestionContainer
    error={ () => this.state.currentError }
    ref="container"
 />
```

then

```
this.refs.container.forceUpdate()
```

dunno if this is the better approach tho

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you pass a **function that returns the value** of `currentError`, instead of just the value itself. Couldn't you just pass it like this:

`<QuestionContainer error={this.state.currentError} /`>

And then, in `QuestionContainer`'s render, use it like e.g.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>{this.props.error}</div>
  )
}
```

If you want your example to work you need to call the function in `QuestionContainer`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>{this.props.error()}</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You may want to include some `var self=this` before you create the array.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have some counter variable in the parent's state and increment it every time you `setState` so if you pass it down to the child it should trigger the child's rerender.